# Route/redirect a path to an "Unauthorized" page in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

An Azure Application Gateway acts as gatekeeper between Internet and API Management in VNET.

**Certain APIs should be publicly accessible**. These whitelisted paths should be routed to APIM, **all others should return a (custom) 401/unauthorised page**.

Actual situation:
A path-based routing rule is set up, assigning the whitelisted paths to correct backend settings&pool. The rule defaults to a „nirvana“ backend pool, so that non-whitelisted requests result in an 502 Bad Gateway.

What I have tried:

- It looks I cannot just „create“ a failure response code out of nowhere, [but only define a custom error page to replace the 502 error in case of backend unavailability and 403 in case of firewall alarm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error).
  My best guess is to spin up a host that always return unauthorised and default redirect there. Is there a better way?
- I played around with rewrite rules, but it seems I can only change headers and target, not the status code itself

Comment: Hi @Robert L., did the suggestion work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   **Yes, there is no way you can create a custom error code page in the Application gateway in case of unauthorized requests and default redirect to pages of certain requests** as `custom error pages for Application gateway only supports ‘502’ and ‘403’ error codes/pages. This is because these are the only codes for which Application gateway would directly serve`, all other codes would be a direct response from the servers hosted in the backend pools.

So, **setting a ‘401’ custom error page on Application gateway is not possible**. The only way is to `configure the backend host to send a ‘401’ response to the Application gateway` or ***enable authentication on the backend site as Application gateway probes can't pass credentials for authentication and will result in ‘401’ error***.

For more detailed information, you can refer to the documentation link below: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#http-status-code-mismatch***